# Complex Numbers $- \arg(-z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

$$\operatorname{Arg}(-z)=\frac{3\pi}4$$

$$\operatorname{Arg}(-z) - \operatorname{Arg} (z) = \pm \pi$$

$$\implies \operatorname{Arg}(z) = \frac{3\pi}4 + \pi = \frac{7\pi}4$$

so, the solution is a line in the complex plane at $315^\circ$.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please [ask a question typeset in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19116/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\operatorname{Arg}(z) \in (-\pi, \pi]$, hence $$\operatorname{Arg}(z) = \frac{7\pi}{4}-2\pi=-\frac{\pi}4$$

It is a half line/ray in the complex plane at $315$ degrees.

Comment: It's more constructive to point OP to the MathJax tutorial than editing the question for him.  Without doing this, new users will +2 rep for "asking a poorly formatted question which will [either get edited or answered](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19116/290189) in a while"

Answer (score 1):

More precisely **the solution is a ray** in the complex plane at 315 degrees.